# No Such Field Error : useGL20

Tags: libgdx

So I upgraded to the latest nightly and updated my project to remove all calls to GL10 but I am getting this error even though I have removed the reference to it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: useGL20
    at com.me.mygdxgame.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

This is what the code in the file looks like

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "my-gdx-game";
                // cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 480;
        cfg.height = 320;

        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of why I still keep getting this error?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to save the file? Maybe Auto-Build is turned off? Maybe clean your projects or refresh them.

Comment: Didn't forget to save the file. Looking into those other things now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest libgdx build has gotten rid of the opengl 1.0 backend so the field cfg.useGL20 is no longer needed. If interested read up [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3311)

According to that page

> LwjglApplicationConfiguration and AndroidApplicationConfiguration do not have the useGL20 flags anymore.

So eliminate that line and things should be good if you updated each project to the newest nightely. If you are still having problems update projects again to the newest nightly as this is very new to libgdx so there are probably a lot of bugs

Comment: I removed all calls to the opengl 1.0 backend. The problem is that I am still getting the error which is strange. I ended up fixing the problem by creating an entirely new project but it's still strange that it wont work when I comment out the cfg.useGL20 = false;
line